# How to update Core Data when data is entered from multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, swift

This is how my view controllers are setup: I have a `Main` view controller which contains a horizontal scrollview and acts as a container. This container has another three view controllers, lets called them `A`, `B` and `C` in which I add different data:

- In `A` I add a start and end time and click Next
- In `B` I add a message string and click Next
- In `C` I add some more data and click Done

In `C`, when Done is pressed I want to save the data from all three view controllers to Core Data.

The way I am doing now is in `C` I just call a `save()` method from `Main` using delegates.

Inside `Main` I just call the `IBOutlets` from `A`, `B` and `C` when saving to Core Data.

I am not sure if this is the right solution.
Is there any other elegant solution for this ? I am looking for something that I could easy unit test.

Comment: Hi Kobe are you Push the view Controllers from A-B and then B-C.

Comment: No, I use modal vc's, I created A, B and C at the begining and load them to the Main vc array of controllers. When I move between them, I am actually using the scrollView, to scroll one vc further.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use a Singleton, although some may disapprove I think in your instance it may be helpful:

```
final class DataCoordinator: NSObject {

private override init() {
print("Data Coordinator Initialized")
}
//Shared Instance:
static let appData = DataCoordinator()

var someVar: String = "" //public variable
fileprivate var mysteryNumber: Int = 0
...
```

and access properties like this:

```
DataCoordinator.appData.someVar
```

make sure you can access the singleton in every VC by calling it from the app delegate...

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
   ...
    print(DataCoordinator.appData)
   ... 
    return true
}
```

you can also have it handle CoreData as well, that is to say you can make the context a shared property within the data coordinator and then access it from any view controller as well as save it with the typical functions:

```
public func saveContext () {
let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
if context.hasChanges {
do {
try context.save()
print("Data Saved to Context")
} catch {
      let nserror = error as NSError
      fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
//use like this
DataCoordinator.appData.saveContext()
```

you may also find it handy to write functions or use didSet to clear variables. Likewise, you can also have the DataCoordinator reload data from CoreData. I am not a big fan of this approach myself but use it when it is appropriate, I strongly suggest you read up on Singletons before implementing one or you may run into some issues down the road.